# Sdcard stated bandwidth at max working hours

Tags: sd, wear-leveling

Sandisk and many sdcard companies state the amount of hours they can work without hitting wear issues.

Usually they state this while recording Full HD video but they don't state how much mbps that is.

Any idea what is commonly used when talking about full HD? How many mega bits per second is that?

Example:
https://shop.westerndigital.com/products/memory-cards/sandisk-high-endurance-uhs-i-microsd#SDSQQNR-032G-AN6IA

Comment: Probably not the right place for this question

Comment: Samsung qualify their statement by Full HD 1920x1080 Video at 26Mbps. That's around 3.25Mbytes per second methinks.

Comment: @Kartman thank you for this, where did you find it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be 100% sure, you should either ask the manufacturer, or ask for a /find a datasheet that gives you some nice graphs for comparisons.

If they are honest (which I doubt), since they give you just the hours, it should not matter how fast you write/read from the card, but just how much time you use it.

I would reccomend you measure it by taking the worst case (Lower read/write speed multiplied by the hours), if you want make a professional estimation.

You can see in [SanDisk's datasheet](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91tTtUMDM3L.pdf) that there is a register that tell you how much life is still in the card. It also tell you that you can still keep using it, but it is not guaranteed it will work just as good.

[image]

I am also pretty sure they (Sandisk engineers) do not know the exact answer to your question either.

Comment: Thank you, the datasheet is for their industrial line, I wonder if they have this registers also in the regular line